# VSS SDK behaves async

Tags: reactjs, azure-devops

I have this block of code

```
    VSS.require(["TFS/WorkItemTracking/Services"], function(workItemServices:any) {
        workItemServices.WorkItemFormService.getService().then(function (workItemFormSvc:any) {             
            if(workItemFormSvc.hasActiveWorkItem()) {
                workItemFormSvc.getFieldValue(["System.Id"]).then(function(value:any){
                    wId = value;
                    console.log("work item id",value);
                });
            }
            else {
                console.log("Active work item is NOT available.");
            }
        });
    });

    VSS.require(["VSS/Service"], function() {
        userId = VSS.getWebContext().user.id;
        console.log("inside require::::", VSS.getWebContext().user.id);
    });     

    this.setState({workItemId : wId}, ()=>console.log(this.state.workItemId));
    this.setState({personId : userId}, ()=> console.log(this.state.personId));
```

`console.log` output as follows

[image]

The ones which are in the red rectangle are from `this.setState` and the ones which have green frame are from `require` scope.

I want to have that values but the assignment operation is accomplished somehow before the value is set from `require` scopes.

How could I handle this?

**Note:** It is denoted in the official documentation that [`require()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/reference/client/core-sdk?view=azure-devops#require--) is async

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to bind the function at constructor, then I store `this` as `refThis` just before `require()` block

```
constructor(props:any){
        
    super(props);
    this.getIds = this.getIds.bind(this);
}

getIds(){
        
    var refThis = this;
    VSS.require(["TFS/WorkItemTracking/Services"], function(workItemServices:any) {

        //get workItemId
        workItemServices.WorkItemFormService.getService().then(function(workItemFormSvc:any) {              
            if(workItemFormSvc.hasActiveWorkItem()) {
                workItemFormSvc.getFieldValue(["System.Id"]).then(function(value:any){
                    // Is there a problem with the following line ? (loadData() has to work after id is assigned)
                    refThis.setState({id:value}, () =>{ refThis.loadData() });
                });
            }
        }));    
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `setState` before `console.log` in `require()`. For example:

```
    VSS.require(["TFS/WorkItemTracking/Services"], function(workItemServices:any) {
    workItemServices.WorkItemFormService.getService().then(function (workItemFormSvc:any) {             
        if(workItemFormSvc.hasActiveWorkItem()) {
            workItemFormSvc.getFieldValue(["System.Id"]).then(function(value:any){
                wId = value;
                this.setState({workItemId : wId}, ()=>console.log(this.state.workItemId));
                console.log("work item id",value);
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log("Active work item is NOT available.");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I already tried that but, here what I get following error, **'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.ts(2683)**